# New event() vs document.createEvent()

Tags: javascript

what's the difference between those two syntax for creating an event ?

```
let event = document.createEvent('Event');
```

and

```
let event = new Event('event');
```

Comment: see the documentation: [Creating and triggering events: The old-fashioned way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#the_old-fashioned_way), and from [Document.createEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent) *'Warning: Many methods used with createEvent, such as initCustomEvent, are deprecated. Use [event constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) instead.'*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is the old fashioned way inspired by Java and supported by older browsers like IE.

The second one is the now preferred one and it uses the Event constructor which is supported by all modern browsers.

You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#the_old-fashioned_way

As stated in the @pilchard comment

Comment: hope you copied that link from my comment ;)

Comment: Hi @pilchard, I didn't see your comment before posting the answer but now I can see we are talking same stuff. Why didn't you posted yours as an answer?

Comment: It was a poorly researched question and didn't warrant an answer, merely a pointer to the documenation (which the OP should have read before posting). But no worries! (and welcome to SO)